# How to generate a byte string consisting of random nonzero bytes using Python?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, rsa

As part of implementing the [PKCS #1 v1.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.2) padding scheme for RSA, I need to **generate an octet string of length n consisting of pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets**.
I'm looking for the best way to do this using Python.

This is what my current implementation looks like:

```py
def nonzero_random_bytes(n: int) -> bytes:
    values = [x.to_bytes(1, "big") for x in range(1, 256)]
    seq = [secrets.choice(values) for _ in range(n)]
    return b"".join(seq)
```

I've looked at generating the byte string with `secrets.token_bytes(n)`, filtering the result, and generating nonzero values to backfill the string. I know I can also do something like `secrets.token_bytes(2 * n)`, filter, and trim the result but that doesn't strike me as an elegant solution.

I've also looked into how [PyCryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py#L109) and [python-pkcs1](https://github.com/bdauvergne/python-pkcs1/blob/master/pkcs1/primitives.py#L113) do this but I'm thinking there must be a better way (I poked around [pyca/cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) <s>but couldn't find how they did it</s> and it seems they use OpenSSL bindings - [here's](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c#L146) where I think that's implemented).

**Disclaimer:** I am aware that I shouldn't use PKCS1 v1.5, much less be rolling out any cryptography code myself. This is purely an academic exercise. :)

Comment: Your idea of starting with `secrets.token_bytes(2 * n)` and trimming zeros is elegant enough. There's just no interface in `secrets` to do this much more elegantly.

Comment: How large is n? Does it need to be fast?

Comment: n is the padding length for RSA, probably 100-400 bytes depending on modulus size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define what "best" means to you. I'd go with this, which is basically a less wordy way of doing what you already did:

```
from secrets import randbelow

def nonzero_random_bytes(n: int) -> bytes:
    return bytes(randbelow(255) + 1 for _ in range(n))
```

Comment: Good point; best would probably be defined here as pythonic while respecting cryptographic good practices. That's a beautiful solution, the `+1` transformation looks so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Ya, it keeps it simple. Filtering is dicier just because it's harder to express. Under the covers, `randbelow()` and `choice()` are already filtering - they pick "the next" string of bits from the source and see whether they represent an integer small enough - and, if not, back to the top of the internal loop to try again. That code has been reviewed by many eyeballs, so is mildly trustworthy by now ;-)

Comment: Where can I see the code of randbelow? I've look and couldn't find, yet.

Comment: There are two implementations in Lib/random.py, methods `_randbelow_with_getrandbits()` and `_randbelow_without_getrandbits()`. `getrandbits()` in turn is implemented in C, function `_random_Random_getrandbits_impl()` in Modules/_randommodule.c.

Comment: Although the version of `getrandbits()` the `secrets` module ends up using is `SystemRandom.getrandbits()` in Lib/random.py.

Answer (score 2):

Had almost the same as Tim but thought "best" might require speed. Benchmark for `n = 250` (middle of the "probably 100-400" range):

```
471.3 us  nonzero_random_bytes_original
438.3 us  nonzero_random_bytes_randbelow
  4.7 us  nonzero_random_bytes_2n
  3.1 us  nonzero_random_bytes_plus10
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNhb4JADIa/8ysaEwM3kQCGZSFxf8QZAlr0tqPHjmPq/rw7ONRtUfjWa5/2zdtSn/Re0uKlVudzqWQFmlfINfCqlkoPkTNEDW4U6sZxtlgCSfpGJTOV01ZWWXHS2GRS8R2nXHiUAifNYP4KfSZ1wHxfuWixgSWsjoGWlvEiHyYF300YlFLB0XBgeu6wS8TJM1v3aIOfHTdICDZ7yTfo2YaWzG4kDZApbRVBMZkE75KTZ5qwEfVdUKCQhwfyL@2sbJhdDAluYJwkd9SMDY1pfNplhpYfSINlMTwBsUBhLXLjQuG@ha4PheuyVUrrkWG1aJsofDiwaYU2LptG/cNhzwUCIW4hXQLBHASSZ8uYZX5xs@VdrT0@gyh8pNfk/2zLtnOcsqVNfyt9cvTc/Mcl19WM1MQ0krSW@Y6x9d9eF4MH3XMntsv0om/WdG7af8gTeVVs87SvMGcSMh@orQpUyygMQ3ZFamVW47nTJIhKaBtwYQqeNguPcGGYDg@yjPIKs8xSlmDn8w8)):

```
from timeit import timeit
import secrets

def nonzero_random_bytes_original(n: int) -> bytes:
    values = [x.to_bytes(1, "big") for x in range(1, 256)]
    seq = [secrets.choice(values) for _ in range(n)]
    return b"".join(seq)

def nonzero_random_bytes_randbelow(n: int) -> bytes:
    return bytes(1 + secrets.randbelow(255) for _ in range(n))

def nonzero_random_bytes_2n(n: int) -> bytes:
    return secrets.token_bytes(2 * n).replace(b'\0', b'')[:n]

def nonzero_random_bytes_plus10(n: int) -> bytes:
    result = b''
    while need := n - len(result):
        result += secrets.token_bytes(need + 10).replace(b'\0', b'')[:need]
    return result

funcs = [
    nonzero_random_bytes_original,
    nonzero_random_bytes_randbelow,
    nonzero_random_bytes_2n,
    nonzero_random_bytes_plus10,
]

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: func(250), number=1000)
        print('%5.1f us ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: I was going to follow up with something similar but this is spectacular. It's good to see my initial intuition of `token_bytes` being the most performant validated. What do you call the technique used in `nonzero_random_bytes_randbelow2`? I'm not too familiar with the benefits of keeping around local reference.

Comment: I don't know whether it has a proper name. Tim would know. I've sometimes called it "localizing". Benefit is that it loads faster, but whether that's significant depends on the overall code.

Comment: In compiler lingo, replacing an operation with a cheaper equivalent is called "strength reduction". Accessing locals is simply faster than accessing globals in CPython. In crypto contexts, "obviously right" is valued over "not obviously wrong". If the speed of the filtering method is important, make it bulletproof: check that the final length _is_ `n`; if it's not, try again.
Some crypto geeks would likely complain that oversampling by a factor of 2 is a Bad Idea, eating up the OS's pool of genuine entropy at twice the rate needed. Doesn't bother me - but I'm not a crypto geek ;-)

Comment: @Tim Peters How would you use "strength reduction" in a sentence to describe what I did there? (I just deleted it, though, as I got conflicting results, so it seemed misleading and distracting.) I might say "I localized secrets.randbelow". Added a "plus 10" solution now to make it bulletproof and less oversampling. Turned out faster as well.

Comment: I'd just say "I bound `secrets.randbelow` to a local name". Everyone has done a similar thing countless times in Python, so everyone knows what it means.